# django-mptt : Filter all categories having an online entry

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-mptt, mptt

I am passing this [Django Blog App](http://gillesfabio.com/blog/2010/07/22/creer-un-blog-avec-django-1-2/) category system to django-mptt.

The problem I have is about the `_get_online_category` method.
This method allows me to get only the category having an `Entry`.

```
def _get_online_categories(self):
    """
    Returns categories with entries "online" inside.
    Access this through the property ``online_entry_set``.
    """
    from models import Entry
    return Category.objects.filter(entries__status=Entry.STATUS_ONLINE).distinct()
```

How can I modify it so I will have also categories having categories having an entry ?

**For example :**

I have `Spain > Malaga` and Malaga got an `Entry` with the previous method, I will get only `Malaga` but not `Spain` I would like to have both.

**Second question :**

How to get all entries from a parent category ?

For exemple get Malaga's post from Spain ?

```
def _get_online_entries(self):
    """
    Returns entries in this category with status of "online".
    Access this through the property ``online_entry_set``.
    """
    from models import Entry        
    return self.entries.filter(status=Entry.STATUS_ONLINE)

online_entries = property(_get_online_entries)
```

This returns empty result for Spain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537695/186202) looks to be a good solution for the first way :

```
def _get_online_categories(self):
    """
    Returns categories with entries "online" inside.
    Access this through the property ``online_entry_set``.
    """
    from models import Entry
    queryset =  self.categories.filter(entries__status=Entry.STATUS_ONLINE)

    new_queryset = queryset.none() | queryset
    for obj in queryset:
        new_queryset = new_queryset | obj.get_ancestors()
    return new_queryset
```

**Second question**

Something like this will make it :

```
def _get_online_entries(self):
    """
    Returns entries in this category with status of "online".
    Access this through the property ``online_entry_set``.
    """
    from models import Entry        
    return Entry.objects.filter(status=Entry.STATUS_ONLINE, 
                                category__lft__gte=self.lft, 
                                category__rght__lte=self.rght)

online_entries = property(_get_online_entries)
```